# Why am I getting a segmentation fault only sometimes?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, gdb, hashtable

I've got a hashtable here, and this program attempts to find anagrams by searching through linked-lists of words whose hash values are computed as the sum of their uppercase ascii values.

I cannot see how this segfault is happening, much less understand what `gdb` is telling me. It's obvious it's happening in `anagramlookup()` but I cannot see how.

Here is the `gdb` output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strspn_sse2 ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strspn.S:53
53      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strspn.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strspn_sse2 ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strspn.S:53
#1  0x0000000000400a0a in anagramlookup (
    word=0x7fffffffe7c0 "you") at thirdfailure.c:66
#2  0x0000000000400c17 in main () at thirdfailure.c:121
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000000000400c17 in main () at thirdfailure.c:121
121             anagramlookup(search);
(gdb) print search
$1 = "you\000\000\177\000\000\221I\336\367\377\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\020\232\377\367\377\177\000\000\001", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\001\000\000\000\377\177\000\000\310\341\377\367\377\177", '\000' <repeats 37 times>
```

The segfault doesn't happen all the time. If the word to lookup is "post", everything works fine. But when it is for example, "you", that's when I get a segfault. "youu" does not give me a segfault. How would I go about fixing things?

and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Hash *hashTable = NULL;

struct Node{
    char val[100];
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Hash{
    int size;
    struct Node *head;
};

struct Node* newnode(char* word){

    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(ptr->val, word);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;

}

void insertHash(char* word){
    int index = hashmaker(word);

    struct Node *ptr = newnode(word);

    if(!hashTable[index].head){
        hashTable[index].head = ptr;
        hashTable[index].size = 1;
        return;
    }
    else{
        ptr->next = (hashTable[index].head);
        hashTable[index].head = ptr;
        hashTable[index].size++;
        return;
    }
}

void anagramlookup(char* word){
    int index = hashmaker(word);

    struct Node *ptr = hashTable[index].head;

    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("we dont have any");
    }
    else{
        while((ptr!= NULL)){
            if(strlen(word)==strspn(word,ptr->val) &&
                strlen(word)==strspn(ptr->val,word) &&
                strlen(word)==strlen(ptr->val)){
                if(strcmp(word,ptr->val) != 0){
                    printf("\n%s", ptr->val );
                }
            }
        ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}


int hashmaker(char* word){

    int toreturn = 0, i, len;
    len = strlen(word);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        toreturn += toupper(word[i]);
    }
    return toreturn;
}


int main(){

    char search[100];


    hashTable = (struct Hash *) malloc(sizeof(struct Hash));

    FILE* dict = fopen("words2", "r");
        if(dict == NULL) {
            printf("dict is null");
            exit(1);
        }
    // Read each line of the file, and print it to screen
    char wordo[128];
    while(fgets(wordo, sizeof(wordo), dict) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", wordo);
        wordo[strlen(wordo) - 1] = '\0';
        insertHash(wordo);
    }

    printf("now enter your search: ");
    fgets(search, sizeof(wordo), stdin);
    search[strlen(search) - 1] = '\0';
    anagramlookup(search);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: whats in your words file?

Comment: Would you like a copy? Otherwise, it's just a list of 10,000 words, one on each line. No spaces, or anything else.

Comment: a copy would be best!

Comment: Here you go, http://pastebin.com/0Ndu6nAs

Comment: Your hash table is a single Hash element, not an array. Yet in insertHash you access hashTable[index] without allocating it first. And hashmaker will return nonzero indexes.

Comment: @tux3 This is my first implementation of a hashtable, and I just started c a few days ago so I'm not sure where to go from here. How should I tweak it?

Comment: You should declare `extern int hashmaker(char* word);` before functions. Always compile with `-Wall` option in gcc.

Comment: A hash table should have as many entries as the range of the hashing function. Your hashing function should probably use a `%` operator to limit the maximum value, and use an `unsigned int` so that it's not negative. Typically you want to avoid collisions, so the table size should be somewhat larger than the number of data items you want to insert into it, but you don't want to make it so large that you waste space.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This was it. Instead of malloc, I calloc'd  an appropriate amount of space for the hashtable in addition to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashTable  is an array of struct Hash but memory for it has not been allocated. You need to know the size of hashTable array and allocate memory to it before accessing it through an index eg. hasTable[idex]. If the size of hashTable is going to be n, allocate the memory as follows

```
hashTable = (struct Hash *) malloc(sizeof(struct Hash) * n);
```

If you do not know the size try with safe number. for example the below change should resolve the crash

```
hashTable = (struct Hash *) malloc(sizeof(struct Hash) * 3000);
```